# Dart Input is not working in vs code or dartped.dev

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Dart Program in VS Code]

I'm new at dart and I'm tring to take input in dart but it gives error when i work on dartpad.dev it gives error "Dart:io not supported". and when i run in VS code it says "Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't."
Anyone could help?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ');
  String fahrenheitInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  double celsius = (double.parse(fahrenheitInput) - 32) * 5 / 9;
  print('The temperature in Celsius is ${celsius.toStringAsFixed(2)} degrees.');
}
```

I'm new at dart and I'm tring to take input in dart but it gives error when i work on dartpad.dev it gives error "Dart:io not supported". and when i run in VS code it says "Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't."